# Is it necessary to encrypt browser data over HTTPS?

Tags: security, https

My temmate proposed me to encrypt login/password before sending them to backend.

We use https so I don't see any reason why I should do it and in what circumstances.

Https itself, by definition, is all about encrypting data and protecting us from "man in the middle" attack.

As for me it is not the reason when someone say that we should protect our client from viruses and sniffers, which he has on its computer, and which can decrypt SSL traffic using kindof RSA algorithms. It is up to the owner of the computer. Antiviruses can cope with that pretty well.

One reason when it could be applied is when we store such data on browsers/client's side (for example in local storage), and I think it is architectural risks. All data should be persisted on backend side and browser should be stateless in a way.

Question: in what cases, if any, we do need to encrypt our data before transferring them over https?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No, it's not necessary. At best it would only add overhead. You'd now have to rely on more external libraries (don't roll your own crypto), which increases your attack surface. You'd have higher code complexity, which even if you're fine with the purely engineering headaches, is bad security in principle - the harder the code is to review, the harder it is to spot vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 3):

You should apply protection to assets (data in this case) when you want to protect it against *something*. It makes sense to encrypt if you have a threat in mind, a usecase where this data would be compromised, which is prevented by the proposed encryption.

By default, it's a standard and accepted thing to send usernames and passwords without further encryption over https. If you can come up with ways why that's not enough for you in your specific case, you may apply further encryption. For example you might want to protect it against man-in-the-middle attackers, say a corporate proxy that has its root cert installed on clients (very common in corporate settings).

Note though that encrypting it is not straightforward at all, key management is relatively difficult. How will the client have the key, how will it store it, how will you revoke it if compromised, and so on.

Usually it's not worth it to go down this route. In some very specific cases, it might be.